# Angular2 routerLink directive dynamic parameter?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Here is an example of `routerLink`

```
<a [routerLink]="['SearchResult', {myParam: 'value'}]">
```

Here myParam is constant. How can I make it dynamic i.e., use state to populate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define an Object in your component and pass it to `routerLink`

**Template**

```ts
<a [routerLink]="['SearchResult', searchParams]">
```

**Compoennt**

```ts
@Component({.....})
export class YourComponent {
  public searchParams = {myParam: 'value'};

  ngAfterViewInit(){
     // change your parameters here. eg.: this.searchParams = {somePrm: 'someValue'}
  }
}
```

---

Alternatively if you only have minor changes or params to pass, you can also do this

```ts
<a [routerLink]="['SearchResult', (state == 'a') ?  {myParam: 'value'} :  {yourParam: 'value'}]">
```

Comment: I am not using TypeScript

Comment: there is nothing specific that is only available to TS, you just need to define the `searchParams` Object in your component and pass it to your `routerLink` . Change anything you want in it until the click happens.

Comment: How do I access the query parameter in the component?

Comment: Use [RouteParams](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/RouteParams-class.html).